# GoDaddy Wildcard Subdomain Forwarding

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, forwarding, wildcard

So I have 2 domains `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

Currently `domain2.com` is setup as a Masked Forward to `domain1.com`. I also need to have wildcard subdomains for `domain2.com` forward to `domain1.com` as well. I can't find a thing in GoDaddy's docs and google isn't helping much either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the answer back from suppoert@godaddy.com

> Unfortunately the wildcard subdomain will need to point to an IP address, and in the case of forwarding, it will be are forwarding IP which you cannot secure.

Make sense. Thanks for looking in to this!

Answer (score 0):

The first few posts of a Google search for "godaddy wildcard subdomain" seem to indicate that this isn't possible, but an e-mail to support@godaddy.com would probably answer this for sure.  However, I've seen with my own GoDaddy account that you can't do this with GoDaddy's DNS interface.

However, another option you might have if you have your own server is to run DNS yourself.  There's a chance this isn't an option as GoDaddy's DNS servers are probably more reliable, but a cheap Linux box running BIND could serve as a name server for your domains, which would allow you to control this however you want.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Got the official response from GoDaddy (see above).